# Iterate trough yaml file in ruby and fetching the required data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml

I have a yaml file with the following struture:

```
market:
  US:
    - prod:
      - page1: sys-admin, client-admin, editor-admin
      - page2: client-admin
      - page3: editor-admin, sys-admin

    - dev:
      - page1: sys-admin, editor-admin
      - page2: sys-admin, client-admin, editor-admin
      - page3: sys-admin, client-admin, editor-admin

  IN:
    - prod:
      - page1: sys-admin, client-admin
      - page2: client-admin, editor-admin
      - page3: editor-admin, sys-admin

    - dev:
      - page1: client-admin, editor-admin
      - page2: sys-admin, client-admin, editor-admin
      - page3: sys-admin, client-admin, editor-admin
```

Now I want a function which returns market name eg. **IN** and page eg. **page1** based on the roles eg. **client-admin**. How should I proceed? I am trying but not able to conclude and come to a proper output. 

Help me out, Guys ! 

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: The logic is not clear. What gives you `IN` and `page1` for the input `client-admin`?

Comment: the program will get input as the role such as sys-admin or editor-admin and my function has to return all the markets and desired pages for which the value is former.

Comment: That is what can be easily guessed. And following that, why should it only return `IN` and `page1`, and not anything else that has `client-admin`?

Comment: it should return everything that has cient-admin. For example i am saying IN and page1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest re thinking the design of your YAML file to make this easier on yourself. Maybe something along the lines of

```
doc = <<Y
market:
  US:
    prod:
      page1: 
        - sys-admin 
        - client-admin 
        - editor-admin
      page2: 
        - client-admin
      page3: 
        - editor-admin
        - sys-admin
Y
```

Then finding the correct pages is easy:

```
locale = 'US' 
environment = 'prod'
user_role = 'client-admin'
h = YAML.load(doc).to_h
h['market'][locale][environment].select do |page,roles| 
  roles.include?(user_role)
end 
#=> {"page1"=>["sys-admin", "client-admin", "editor-admin"], 
#    "page2"=>["client-admin"]}
```

Right now your environments are an `Array` of `Hash` objects which seems unnecessary as they could just be a `Hash` and your roles are actually a `String` (e.g. "sys-admin, client-admin, editor-admin") which could be come more difficult to maintain in the future and makes parsing a bit more cumbersome.

Comment: can you please give me the json output for the query

Comment: @AkshatUppal not sure what JSON has to do with this question. Why are you converting YAML to JSON? Either way the JSON would be `"{\"page1\":[\"sys-admin\",\"client-admin\",\"editor-admin\"],\"page2\":[\"client-admin\"]}"`